# Bread::Board - Injecting parameters with ArrayRef type constraints?

Tags: perl, moose, bread-board

Using [`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) and [`Bread::Board`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Bread%3a%3aBoard), is it possible to create an object with an attribute that has an `ArrayRef[SomeObject]` type constraint and have that parameter injected in such a way that:

- The `ArrayRef` constraint is maintained,
- Each object that is a member of that ArrayRef has all of its dependencies met by `Bread::Board`, and
- Each object that is a member of that ArrayRef is an object that was created by `Bread::Board`?

In order to make sure that I'm explaining myself clearly, let's consider an incredibly naive example. Let's say we have a `Wheel` class:

```
package Wheel;
use Moose;

has ['size', 'maker'] => (isa => 'Str', is => 'rw', required => 1);
```

And let's create a `Vehicle` class where each instance contains a bunch of wheels:

```
package Vehicle;
use Moose;

has 'wheels' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'ArrayRef[Wheel]',
    required => 1,
);
```

Is it then possible to create one or more instances of `Wheel` and then inject an array reference containing those instances into our new `Vehicle` instance? This obviously won't work:

```
my $c = container 'app' => as {
    container 'wheels' => as {
        service 'maker' => "Bob's Tires";
        service 'size' => "195R65/15";
        service 'carTires' => (
            class   => 'Wheel',
            dependencies => [ depends_on('maker'), depends_on('size') ],
        )
    };

    container 'vehicles' => as {
        service 'sedan' => (
            class   => 'Vehicle',
            dependencies => {
                # WON'T WORK
                wheels => depends_on('/wheels/carTires'),
            }
        )
    };
};
my $v = $c->resolve(service => 'vehicles/sedan');
```

Any ideas? Yes, I am aware that it my `Vehicle`s can conceivably have no wheels and that I'm trying to create a one-wheeled sedan, but I think you get my point. :-) This is intended only to be an incredibly trivial example.

Comment: this is old, and I don't want to type out a long answer, but [my blog post on using providers](http://www.xenoterracide.com/2013/10/providing-with-providers-and-breadboard.html) might help people solving problems like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the carTires service to return a ArrayRef of Wheels:

```
container 'wheels' => as {
    service 'carTires' => (
        block => sub {
            return [ map {Wheel->new} 1..4 ];
        },
    )
};
```

The Vehicle constructor will take care of the rest in terms of the type constraint, since you've already defined it as ArrayRef[Wheel].

So it will die if you did this instead:

```
container 'wheels' => as {
    service 'carTires' => (
        block => sub {
            return [ map {Window->new} 1..4 ];
        },
    )
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I've re-phrased my original question to add the additional caveat that `Wheel` also has dependencies that need to be met - would using block injection in a similar manner still be the right solution?

Comment: I would think so since block injection is the most flexible in terms of what you can do with it. The problem with the other injection methods is I can't see where we can use them to create an ArrayRef of multiple object instances.